# Error reading SentOnBehalfOfName when accepting invite

Tags: vba, outlook

I bcc a certain mailbox when I use my teams DL to answer emails.

I made the below script to check and apply.

When I accept or decline an invite it throws error at the line:

```
If Item.SentOnBehalfOfName = "my teams name here" Then
```

Error msg:

> Run-time error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim olkRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
    If Item.SentOnBehalfOfName = "my teams name here" Then
        Set olkRecipient = Item.Recipients.Add("my teams dl here")
        olkRecipient.Type = olBCC
        Item.Save
    Else:
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`SentOnBehalfOfName` is a propery of the [MailItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-object-outlook) object, which are used to represent emails.

However, invites are represented as either the [AppointmentItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/appointmentitem-object-outlook) or [MeetingItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/meetingitem-object-outlook) objects intead. You will need to use one of their properties intead, namely the `SendUsingAccount`.

Comment: Thank you, added an extra elseif for checking that, now works like a charm!